# Two post methods in one class based view

Tags: python, django, api

Is there possibility to have 2 post methods in one class based view?

I tried to do something like this but of course it doesn't work

My custom view:

```
class UserExamDetail(APIView):

    def get_queryset(self, pk):
        return Exam.objects.get(pk=pk)

    def get(self, request, pk):
        exam = self.get_queryset(pk=pk)
        if exam:
            exam_closed = 0
            exam_opened = 0
            c_questions = ClosedQuestion.objects.filter(exam=exam)
            o_questions = OpenedQuestion.objects.filter(exam=exam)
            for question in c_questions:
                points = int(question.points)
                exam_closed += points
            for question in o_questions:
                points = int(question.points)
                exam_opened += points
            exam.score = exam_closed + exam_opened
            exam.save()
        serializer = ExamCreatorSerializer(exam)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, pk):
        serializer = ClosedQuestionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(exam=pk)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def post(self, request, pk):
        serializer = OpenedQuestionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(exam=pk)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Only first post works and when i try to change function name on for example: post1 and post 2 then Django won't recognize this method as post. If there is possibility to do this, then I'm also curious if I should do this kind of view or maybe Post methods should be separate views?

Comment: In the code only the serializer change, so you should be abble to combine the two in the same post function and do some if to use one serializer over the other one. You can maybe pass another parameter to the view.

Comment: Can you explain the condition for this case? What situation makes you to require something like two post methods?\

Comment: No. You can have only one post method. You need to add a condition to change the serializer

Comment: So this is app which task is to make exam(model "Exam"), and first in another view I create exam, and then I'm going to detail view of this new exam where I can add questions, and there are 2 types of questions. closed(model "ClosedQuestion) and opened(model "OpenedQuestion") and i want have possibility to add this 2 types of question in one view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass additional data to the request body and decide which serializer to use. Here is an example.

```
def post(self, request, pk):
    if request.POST.get('is_opened'):
        serializer_class = OpenedQuestionSerializer
    else:
        serializer_class = ClosedQuestionSerializer

    serializer = serializer_class(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(exam=pk)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: ok, but how view will know which serializer use, I must probably use different url yes? But then it will be just 2 different views

Comment: But it still will be better, because I won't have to write two very similar class based views. So concluding i must create two urls to choose which serializer use yes?

Comment: Just include `is_opened` with some value to your request body in case if you want to use `OpenedQuestionSerializer`.

Comment: Is there no way to specify a custom method name when using `.to_view(method=...)` in the routes, or something? (To override the behavior of matching request method to class method...). Then OP could name their function anything, no need for two `post` functions.